# How can I do a pop-up like explorer.exe in C# WinForms?

Tags: c#, windows

When we got an error message box in explorer.exe, this pop-up doesn't create another tab in status bar. But when I tried like:

```
MessageBox.Show("Error!");
```

in Windows Forms, this MessageBox is a separate tab. How can I perform all tabs in a single button? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible without some pinvoke win32 libraries.

You could create your own form and set the `ShowInTaskbar` property to false. Use the `ShowDialog()` instead of `Show()`, this will make your form modal.